# How to replace a single word in multiple files with different words in a database

Tags: visual-studio, replace, notepad++

Say **10 files serially named 1-10.json** contain the word/string
**Yolo**

I want **file 1 yolo** to be replaced by **GME**
I want **file 2 yolo** to be replaced by **AMC**
I want **file 3 yolo** to be replaced by **BB**

so basically

10 yolos in different files changed to GME AMC BB serially

I got notepad++ & a 1000 Yolos, I can Ctrl H yolo to GME in all but I want 1000 serial words in one go
what do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm glad to know what you want, but, what have you tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, it appears to need a program. As you have tagged the question with [tag:visual-studio] perhaps you should write such a program.